# How should I implement my C++ exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, shared-libraries

Let's say I have a C++ library. The library will in some cases throw exceptions. I would like to make it possible and simple for a user of this library to catch these exceptions and tell what went wrong. What's the best way to deal with it? I've come up with the following possible solutions:

1. Just use the standart exception classes with custom error messages. This would however make it annoying for someone who catches the exception to tell what was wrong.
2. Create a subclass of `std::exception` and throw that. Add some sort of error code (maybe an enum? or a macro?) so that the user can check what went wrong.
3. Create multiple exception subclasses: one for each possible occasion an exception can be thrown. This seems like a neat idea but I think it's too excessive to create a subclass for every possible error.

I can't really decide. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Exception hierarchies are fundamental to maintainable c++ programs and libraries. Answers to this question carry important information about accepted best practice. The question should not be on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions that occur because the program has been incorrectly written should be derived from `std::logic_error`. Examples of this are indices that are out of bounds. A `std::logic_error` is an error you would expect not to occur and most programs will not be able to recover from them.

Exceptions that are recoverable (i.e. something cannot be done due to a resource being unavailable) should be derived from `std::runtime_error`.

The **type** of the exception should explain what went wrong. Any ancillary information that might be of interest to a developer can go in the `what()` string. If you want to deliver a chain of causation to the developer then consider using `std::throw_with_nested`. This allows an interested developer to forensically discover why his operation failed without having to go through your source code.

Consider using a hierarchy of exceptions. This allows a consumer of your class to code for a general failure condition easily, while allowing him test for individual failures if they are important.

a contrived example:

```
struct failed_to_start : std::runtime_error { 
  using std::runtime_error::runtime_error; 
};

struct engine_fault : failed_to_start { 
  using std::failed_to_start::failed_to_start; 
};

struct engine_flooded : engine_fault { 
  using std::engine_fault::engine_fault; 
};

struct wrong_key : std::logic_error {
  using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};
```

EDIT:
by request, full working example of the use of throw_with_nested (and a few other useful techniques)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>


enum class key {
    none, mine, yours
};

struct out_of_fuel : std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

struct no_key : std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

struct start_failure : std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

struct wrong_key_error : std::logic_error {
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};

struct car_configuration_error : std::logic_error {
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};

struct fuel_tank {
    fuel_tank(double initial) : _quantity { initial } {}

    void remove_fuel(double amount) {
        using namespace std;
        if (amount > _quantity) {
            throw out_of_fuel { "fuel tank has "s
                + to_string(_quantity)
                + " litres remaining, tried to remove "s
                + to_string(amount) };
        }
        _quantity -= amount;
    }

    double _quantity = 0.0;
};

struct ignition {
    ignition(key k) : _key_type { k } {}

    void insert_key(key k) {
        if (_key_type != k) {
            throw wrong_key_error { "the wrong key was inserted" };
        }
        _current_key = k;
    }

    void turn_key() {
        if (_current_key != _key_type) {
            throw no_key { "there is no key in the ignition" };
        }
    }

    key _current_key = key::none;
    const key _key_type;
};

struct engine {
    void run() {

    }

};

struct car {
    car(key k, double initial_fuel)
    : _ignition(k)
    , _fuel_tank(initial_fuel)
    {}

    void start(key k)
    try
    {
        _ignition.insert_key(k);
        _ignition.turn_key();
        _fuel_tank.remove_fuel(1);
        _engine.run();
    }
    catch(const std::logic_error& e) {
        std::throw_with_nested(car_configuration_error { "car configuration error - please check your program" });
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::throw_with_nested(start_failure { "failed to start car" });
    }

    ignition _ignition;
    engine _engine;
    fuel_tank _fuel_tank;
};

void print_current_exception(int level = 0);

void print_exception(const std::exception&e, const char* prefix, int level)
{
    std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << prefix << ": " << e.what() << '\n';
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    }
    catch(const std::exception&) {
        print_current_exception(level + 1);
    }
}

void print_current_exception(int level)
{
    auto eptr = std::current_exception();
    if (!eptr)
        return;

    try {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
    catch(const std::logic_error& e) {
        print_exception(e, "logic error", level);
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& e) {
        print_exception(e, "runtime error", level);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        print_exception(e, "exception", level);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    car my_car { key::mine, .05 };
    car your_car { key::yours, 100 };

    try {
        my_car.start(key::mine);
    }
    catch(const std::exception&) {
        print_current_exception();
    }

    try {
        your_car.start(key::mine);
    }
    catch(const std::exception&) {
        print_current_exception();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
runtime error: failed to start car
 runtime error: fuel tank has 0.050000 litres remaining, tried to remove 1.000000
logic error: car configuration error - please check your program
 logic error: the wrong key was inserted
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate more on `std::throw_with_nested`?

Comment: @Venemo answer updated with compilable example.

Answer (score 7):

> 3. Create multiple exception subclasses: one for each possible occasion an exception can be thrown. This seems like a neat idea but I think it's too excessive to create a subclass for every possible error.

This, for the reason you stated: your users can then catch exactly what they want to catch.

In short, use exceptions as they were intended to be used.

> 2. Create a subclass of `std::exception` and throw that. Add some sort of error code (maybe an enum? or a macro?) so that the user can check what went wrong.

You may wish to throw in a *little* of this approach, where one semantic type of exception has "subcategories" or other auxiliary data that you'd never want to filter on, but may be of secondary interest to your users.